# How to enable Inspect function within right-click menu on custom dialog when debugging Google apps script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, chrome-debugging

I'm developing a file picker function in Google sheet, using Google Picker API. Now I'm able to show a custom dialog window to pick files from my Google drive, but the result doesn't fully meet my needs, I would like to debug and find out any wrong script in HTML which shows in the dialog window. However, when I right-click and select Inspect in a new popup window, it's grey and invalid, unable to debug. What's wrong? Does our company's Google manager restrict users to debug?

Here is a screenshot to show my problem:

[image: Unable to run Inspect to debug HTML code in Google custom dialog window]

Comment: Hello, can you provide more information on your setup? How are you showing this file picker on the first place?

Comment: You can view this video for guide.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgGC2y6qJCM

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to click outside of the modal and inspect it?

You can also press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the developer tools.

Also, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  will open the developer tools with the element picker tool selected.

Comment: No, I'm not able to click outside of the modal window. Others become inactive. F12 doesn't work, and ctrl+shift+C doesn't either.

Comment: What operating system and browser are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, and using Chrome.